# Why would all my bower .css files get ignore but not .js

Tags: gulp, wiredep, gulp-inject, grunt-wiredep

I am running the following task and all my .js files get inserted correctly between   inside css tags, however, the story is the the same for html.

What could be the reason, all my configurations seem to be correct.

```
gulp.task('wiredep', function () {
var wiredep = require('wiredep').stream;

return gulp
    .src(config.index)
    .pipe(wiredep(config.wiredepDefaultOptions))      //wiredep injection configuration
    .pipe($.inject(gulp.src(config.js)))              //custom js files configuation
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.client))
});
```